# Keep target address of load in register until instruction is retired

Tags: c, assembly, intel, cpu-registers, performancecounter

I want to use Precise Event-Based Sampling (PEBS) to record all the addresses of specific events (say cache misses for example), on a XeonE5 Sandy Bridge.

However, the *Performance Analysis Guide for Core<sup>TM</sup> i7 Processor and Intel® XeonTM 5500 processors*, p.24, contains the following warning:

> As the PEBS mechanism captures the values of the register at
> completion of the instruction, the dereferenced address for the
> following type of load instruction (Intel asm convention) cannot be
> reconstructed.
>  `MOV RAX, [RAX+const]`
>  This kind of
> instruction is mostly associated with pointer chasing
> `mystruc = mystruc->next;`
> This is a significant shortcoming of this
> approach to capturing memory instruction addresses.

I have a number of load instructions of that form in my program according to objdump. **Is there any way I can avoid those?**

As this is a intel specific problem, the solution does not have to be portable in any way, it just has to work. My code is written in C, and I'm ideally looking for a compiler-level solution (gcc or icc) but any suggestions are welcome.

---

Some examples:

```
mov    0x18(%rdi),%rdi

mov    (%rcx,%rax,8),%rax
```

In both cases, after the instruction retired (thus when I look at the register values to figure out where I loaded to/from) the values of the addresses (respectively `%rdi + 18` and `%rcx + 8 * %rax` in these examples) are overwritten by the result of the `mov`.

---

The only way I can think of right now is to use the & (ampersand) assembler constraint. That would mean I would have to go through my code wherever such an instruction appears, and replace every pointer dereferencing `mystruc = mystruc->next;` with something like:
`asm volatile("mov (%1),%0" : "=&r" (mystruc) : "r" (&(mystruc->next)))`

However it is a very pedestrian approach and there are probably cases that are more complicated than a pointer inside a struct. I understand this is basically increasing register pressure so something compilers are actively trying to avoid. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It would probably be a lot of work to hack up gcc or clang to try to avoid loads that overwrite one of their inputs.  There might be some infrastructure for caring about more than just register pressure, though, because Intel P6 (ppro to nehalem) likes it when you read from registers that were written recently.  Too many reads from old registers (where the value has been committed from the ROB to the permanent register file) will lead to register-read stalls.  SnB changed to a phys register file design and a level of indirection in the ROB, and doesn't suffer from register-read stalls at all.

Comment: Anyway, compilers might already be able to favour overwriting different registers, because optimizing for P6 was a thing for many years.  But they won't do it when it costs extra instructions.  A pointer-chasing loop would have to be unrolled to not spend an extra mov instruction.

Comment: Not overwriting is one option, maybe copying the address before overwriting is another. I read on IBM architectures this is done automatically when using event-based sampling, using a dedicated register, the Sampled Data Address Register (SDAR). Maybe emulating this is a more promising lead?

Comment: Maybe using an intermediate variable to which assign the pointer, than using the last to update and compiling with **no optimization**. I.e. `mystruct_t *pTmp = mystruct->next; mystruct = pTmp;`. The drawback is all code unoptimized.

Comment: @Frankie_C that's pretty much what the assembly does, except you can still optimize the rest of the code. And that means I still have to go through all the places in the code that will compile to such an instruction manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you'd like to do is transform all instructions of the form:

```
mov    (%rcx,%rax,8),%rax
```

Into:

```
mov    (%rcx,%rax,8),%r11
mov    %r11,%rax
```

---

This can be done much more easily by modifying the assembler source generated by the compiler. Below is a `perl` script that will do all the necessary transformations by reading and modifying the `.s` file.

Just change the build to produce `.s` files instead of `.o` files, apply the script, and then generate the `.o` with either `as` or `gcc`

---

Here's the actual script. I've tested it on a few of my own sources, following the build procedure in the comments below.

The script has the following features:

1. scans and locates all function definitions
2. identifies all registers used in a given function
3. locates all return points for the function
4. selects a temporary register to use based upon the function's register usage (i.e. it will use a temporary register that is *not* already in use by the function)
5. replaces all "troublesome" instructions with a two instruction sequence
6. tries to use unused temporary registers (e.g. `%r11` or unused argument registers) before trying to use a *callee* saved register
7. if the selected register is *callee* saved, will add `push` to function prolog and `pop` to function [multiple] `ret` statements
8. maintains a log of all analysis and transformations and appends this as comments to the output `.s` file

---

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# pebsfix/pebsfixup -- fix assembler source for PEBS usage
#
# command line options:
#   "-a" -- use only full 64 bit targets
#   "-l" -- do _not_ use lea
#   "-D[diff-file]" -- show differences (default output: "./DIFF")
#   "-n10" -- do _not_ use register %r10 for temporary (default is use it)
#   "-o" -- overwrite input files (can be multiple)
#   "-O<outfile>" -- output file (only one .s input allowed)
#   "-q" -- suppress warnings
#   "-T[lvl]" -- debug trace
#
# "-o" and "-O" are mutually exclusive
#
# command line script test options:
#   "-N[TPA]" -- disable temp register types [for testing]
#   "-P" -- force push/pop on all functions
#
# command line arguments:
#   1-- list of .s files to process [or directory to search]
#       for a given file "foo.s", output is to "foo.TMP"
#       if (-o is given, "foo.TMP" is renamed to "foo.s")
#
# suggested usage:
#   change build to produce .s files
#   FROM:
#     cc [options] -c foo.c
#   TO:
#     cc [options] -c -S foo.c
#     pebsfixup -o foo.s
#     cc -c foo.s
#
# suggested compiler options:
# [probably only really needed if push/pop required. use -NP to verify]
#   (1) use either of
#       -O2 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls
#       -O1
#   (2) use -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer
#   (3) use -mno-red-zone [probably not required in any case]
#
# NOTES:
#   (1) red zones are only really useful for leaf functions (i.e. if fncA calls
#       fncB, fncA's red zone would be clobbered)
#   (2) pushing onto the stack isn't a problem if there is a formal stack frame
#   (3) the push is okay if the function has no more than six arguments (i.e.
#       does _not_ use positive offsets from %rsp to access them)

#pragma pgmlns
use strict qw(vars subs);

our $pgmtail;

our $opt_a;
our $opt_T;
our $opt_D;
our $opt_l;
our $opt_n10;
our $opt_N;
our $opt_P;
our $opt_q;
our $opt_o;
our $opt_O;
our $opt_s;

our @reguse;
our %reguse_tobase;
our %reguse_isbase;
our $regusergx;

our @regtmplist;
our %regtmp_type;

our $diff;

our $sepflg;
our $fatal;
our @cmtprt;

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($xfsrc);
    my($file,@files);
    my($bf);

    $pgmtail = "pebsfixup";

    optget(\@argv);

    # define all known/usable registers
    regusejoin();

    # define all registers that we may use as a temporary
    regtmpall();

    if (defined($opt_D)) {
        unlink($opt_D);
    }

    # show usage
    if (@argv <= 0) {
        $file = $0;
        open($xfsrc,"<$file") ||
            sysfault("$pgmtail: unable to open '%s' -- $!\n",$file);

        while ($bf = <$xfsrc>) {
            chomp($bf);
            next if ($bf =~ /^#!/);
            last unless ($bf =~ s/^#//);
            $bf =~ s/^# ?//;
            print($bf,"\n");
        }

        close($xfsrc);
        exit(1);
    }

    foreach $file (@argv) {
        if (-d $file) {
            dodir(\@files,$file);
        }
        else {
            push(@files,$file);
        }
    }

    if (defined($opt_O)) {
        sysfault("$pgmtail: -O may have only one input file\n")
            if (@files != 1);
        sysfault("$pgmtail: -O and -o are mutually exclusive\n")
            if ($opt_o);
    }

    foreach $file (@files) {
        dofile($file);
    }

    if (defined($opt_D)) {
        exec("less",$opt_D);
    }
}

# dodir -- process directory
sub dodir
{
    my($files,$dir) = @_;
    my($file,@files);

    @files = (`find $dir -type f -name '*.s'`);
    foreach $file (@files) {
        chomp($file);
        push(@$files,$file);
    }
}

# dofile -- process file
sub dofile
{
    my($file) = @_;
    my($ofile);
    my($xfsrc);
    my($xfdst);
    my($bf,$lno,$outoff);
    my($fixoff);
    my($lhs,$rhs);
    my($xop,$arg);
    my($ix);
    my($sym,$val,$typ);
    my(%sym_type);
    my($fnc,$fnx,%fnx_lookup,@fnxlist);
    my($retlist);
    my($uselook,@uselist,%avail);
    my($fixreg,$fixrtyp);
    my($sixlist);
    my($fix,$fixlist);
    my($fixtot);
    my(@fix);
    my(@outlist);
    my($relaxflg);
    my($cmtchr);

    undef($fatal);
    undef(@cmtprt);

    msgprt("\n")
        if ($sepflg);
    $sepflg = 1;
    msgprt("$pgmtail: processing %s ...\n",$file);

    $cmtchr = "#";

    cmtprt("%s\n","-" x 78);
    cmtprt("FILE: %s\n",$file);

    # get the output file
    $ofile = $file;
    sysfault("$pgmtail: bad suffix -- file='%s'\n",$file)
        unless ($ofile =~ s/[.]s$//);
    $ofile .= ".TMP";

    # use explicit output file
    if (defined($opt_O)) {
        $ofile = $opt_O;
        sysfault("$pgmtail: output file may not be input file -- use -o instead\n")
            if ($ofile eq $file);
    }

    open($xfsrc,"<$file") ||
        sysfault("$pgmtail: unable to open '%s' -- $!\n",$file);

    $lno = 0;
    while ($bf = <$xfsrc>) {
        chomp($bf);
        $bf =~ s/\s+$//;

        $outoff = $lno;
        ++$lno;

        push(@outlist,$bf);

        # clang adds comments
        $ix = index($bf,"#");
        if ($ix >= 0) {
            $bf = substr($bf,0,$ix);
            $bf =~ s/\s+$//;
        }

        # look for ".type blah, @function"
        # NOTE: this always comes before the actual label line [we hope ;-)]
        if ($bf =~ /^\s+[.]type\s+([^,]+),\s*(\S+)/) {
            ($sym,$val) = ($1,$2);
            $val =~ s/^\@//;
            $sym_type{$sym} = $val;
            cmtprt("\n");
            cmtprt("TYPE: %s --> %s\n",$sym,$val);
            next;
        }

        # look for "label:"
        if ($bf =~ /^([a-z_A-Z][a-z_A-Z0-9]*):$/) {
            $sym = $1;
            next if ($sym_type{$sym} ne "function");

            $fnc = $sym;
            cmtprt("FUNCTION: %s\n",$fnc);

            $fnx = {};
            $fnx_lookup{$sym} = $fnx;
            push(@fnxlist,$fnx);

            $fnx->{fnx_fnc} = $fnc;
            $fnx->{fnx_outoff} = $outoff;

            $uselook = {};
            $fnx->{fnx_used} = $uselook;

            $retlist = [];
            $fnx->{fnx_retlist} = $retlist;

            $fixlist = [];
            $fnx->{fnx_fixlist} = $fixlist;

            $sixlist = [];
            $fnx->{fnx_sixlist} = $sixlist;
            next;
        }

        # remember all registers used by function:
        while ($bf =~ /($regusergx)/gpo) {
            $sym = ${^MATCH};
            $val = $reguse_tobase{$sym};
            dbgprt(3,"dofile: REGUSE sym='%s' val='%s'\n",$sym,$val);

            $uselook->{$sym} += 1;

            $uselook->{$val} += 1
                if ($val ne $sym);
        }

        # handle returns
        if ($bf =~ /^\s+ret/) {
            push(@$retlist,$outoff);
            next;
        }
        if ($bf =~ /^\s+rep[a-z]*\s+ret/) {
            push(@$retlist,$outoff);
            next;
        }

        # split up "movq 16(%rax),%rax" ...
        $ix = rindex($bf,",");
        next if ($ix < 0);

        # ... into "movq 16(%rax)"
        $lhs = substr($bf,0,$ix);
        $lhs =~ s/\s+$//;

        # check for "movq 16(%rsp)" -- this means that the function has/uses
        # more than six arguments (i.e. we may _not_ push/pop because it
        # wreaks havoc with positive offsets)
        # FIXME/CAE -- we'd have to adjust them by 8 which we don't do
        (undef,$rhs) = split(" ",$lhs);
        if ($rhs =~ /^(\d+)[(]%rsp[)]$/) {
            push(@$sixlist,$outoff);
            cmtprt("SIXARG: %s (line %d)\n",$rhs,$lno);
        }

        # ... and "%rax"
        $rhs = substr($bf,$ix + 1);
        $rhs =~ s/^\s+//;

        # target must be a [simple] register [or source scan will blow up]
        # (e.g. we actually had "cmp %ebp,(%rax,%r14)")
        next if ($rhs =~ /[)]/);

        # ensure we have the "%" prefix
        next unless ($rhs =~ /^%/);

        # we only want the full 64 bit reg as target
        # (e.g. "mov (%rbx),%al" doesn't count)
        $val = $reguse_tobase{$rhs};
        if ($opt_a) {
            next if ($val ne $rhs);
        }
        else {
            next unless (defined($val));
        }

        # source operand must contain target [base] register
        next unless ($lhs =~ /$val/);
        ###cmtprt("1: %s,%s\n",$lhs,$rhs);

        # source operand must be of the "right" type
        # FIXME/CAE -- we may need to revise this
        next unless ($lhs =~ /[(]/);
        cmtprt("NEEDFIX: %s,%s (line %d)\n",$lhs,$rhs,$lno);

        # remember the place we need to fix for later
        $fix = {};
        push(@$fixlist,$fix);
        $fix->{fix_outoff} = $outoff;
        $fix->{fix_lhs} = $lhs;
        $fix->{fix_rhs} = $rhs;
    }

    close($xfsrc);

    # get total number of fixups
    foreach $fnx (@fnxlist) {
        $fixlist = $fnx->{fnx_fixlist};
        $fixtot += @$fixlist;
    }
    msgprt("$pgmtail: needs %d fixups\n",$fixtot)
        if ($fixtot > 0);

    # fix each function
    foreach $fnx (@fnxlist) {
        cmtprt("\n");
        cmtprt("FNC: %s\n",$fnx->{fnx_fnc});

        $fixlist = $fnx->{fnx_fixlist};

        # get the fixup register
        ($fixreg,$fixrtyp) = regtmploc($fnx,$fixlist);

        # show number of return points
        {
            $retlist = $fnx->{fnx_retlist};
            cmtprt("  RET: %d\n",scalar(@$retlist));
            last if (@$retlist >= 1);

            # NOTE: we display this warning because we may not be able to
            # handle all situations

            $relaxflg = (@$fixlist <= 0) || ($fixrtyp ne "P");
            last if ($relaxflg && $opt_q);

            errprt("$pgmtail: in file '%s'\n",$file);
            errprt("$pgmtail: function '%s' has no return points\n",
                $fnx->{fnx_fnc});
            errprt("$pgmtail: suggest recompile with correct options\n");

            if (@$fixlist <= 0) {
                errprt("$pgmtail: working around because function needs no fixups\n");
                last;
            }

            if ($fixrtyp ne "P") {
                errprt("$pgmtail: working around because fixup reg does not need to be saved\n");
                last;
            }
        }

        # show stats on register usage in function
        $uselook = $fnx->{fnx_used};
        @uselist = sort(keys(%$uselook));
        cmtprt("  USED:\n");
        %avail = %reguse_isbase;
        foreach $sym (@uselist) {
            $val = $uselook->{$sym};

            $typ = $regtmp_type{$sym};
            $typ = sprintf(" (TYPE: %s)",$typ)
                if (defined($typ));

            cmtprt("    %s used %d%s\n",$sym,$val,$typ);
            $val = $reguse_tobase{$sym};
            delete($avail{$val});
        }

        # show function's available [unused] registers
        @uselist = keys(%avail);
        @uselist = sort(regusesort @uselist);
        if (@uselist > 0) {
            cmtprt("  AVAIL:\n");
            foreach $sym (@uselist) {
                $typ = $regtmp_type{$sym};
                $typ = sprintf(" (TYPE: %s)",$typ)
                    if (defined($typ));
                cmtprt("    %s%s\n",$sym,$typ);
            }
        }

        # skip over any functions that don't need fixing _and_ have a temp
        # register
        if (@$fixlist <= 0 && (! $opt_P)) {
            next if (defined($fixreg));
        }

        msgprt("$pgmtail: function %s\n",$fnx->{fnx_fnc});

        # skip function because we don't have a fixup register but report it
        # here
        unless (defined($fixreg)) {
            $bf = (@$fixlist > 0) ? "FATAL" : "can be ignored -- no fixups needed";
            msgprt("$pgmtail: FIXNOREG (%s)\n",$bf);
            cmtprt("  FIXNOREG (%s)\n",$bf);
            next;
        }

        msgprt("$pgmtail: FIXREG --> %s (TYPE: %s)\n",$fixreg,$fixrtyp);
        cmtprt("  FIXREG --> %s (TYPE: %s)\n",$fixreg,$fixrtyp);

        foreach $fix (@$fixlist) {
            $outoff = $fix->{fix_outoff};

            undef(@fix);
            cmtprt("  FIXOLD %s\n",$outlist[$outoff]);

            # original
            if ($opt_l) {
                $bf = sprintf("%s,%s",$fix->{fix_lhs},$fixreg);
                push(@fix,$bf);
                $bf = sprintf("\tmov\t%s,%s",$fixreg,$fix->{fix_rhs});
                push(@fix,$bf);
            }

            # use lea
            else {
                ($xop,$arg) = split(" ",$fix->{fix_lhs});
                $bf = sprintf("\tlea\t\t%s,%s",$arg,$fixreg);
                push(@fix,$bf);
                $bf = sprintf("\t%s\t(%s),%s",$xop,$fixreg,$fix->{fix_rhs});
                push(@fix,$bf);
            }

            foreach $bf (@fix) {
                cmtprt("  FIXNEW %s\n",$bf);
            }

            $outlist[$outoff] = [@fix];
        }

        unless ($opt_P) {
            next if ($fixrtyp ne "P");
        }

        # fix the function prolog
        $outoff = $fnx->{fnx_outoff};
        $lhs = $outlist[$outoff];
        $rhs = sprintf("\tpush\t%s",$fixreg);
        $bf = [$lhs,$rhs,""];
        $outlist[$outoff] = $bf;

        # fix the function return points
        $retlist = $fnx->{fnx_retlist};
        foreach $outoff (@$retlist) {
            $rhs = $outlist[$outoff];
            $lhs = sprintf("\tpop\t%s",$fixreg);
            $bf = ["",$lhs,$rhs];
            $outlist[$outoff] = $bf;
        }
    }

    open($xfdst,">$ofile") ||
        sysfault("$pgmtail: unable to open '%s' -- $!\n",$ofile);

    # output all the assembler text
    foreach $bf (@outlist) {
        # ordinary line
        unless (ref($bf)) {
            print($xfdst $bf,"\n");
            next;
        }

        # apply a fixup
        foreach $rhs (@$bf) {
            print($xfdst $rhs,"\n");
        }
    }

    # output all our reasoning as comments at the bottom
    foreach $bf (@cmtprt) {
        if ($bf eq "") {
            print($xfdst $cmtchr,$bf,"\n");
        }
        else {
            print($xfdst $cmtchr," ",$bf,"\n");
        }
    }

    close($xfdst);

    # get difference
    if (defined($opt_D)) {
        system("diff -u $file $ofile >> $opt_D");
    }

    # install fixed/modified file
    {
        last unless ($opt_o || defined($opt_O));
        last if ($fatal);
        msgprt("$pgmtail: installing ...\n");
        rename($ofile,$file);
    }
}

# regtmpall -- define all temporary register candidates
sub regtmpall
{

    dbgprt(1,"regtmpall: ENTER\n");

    regtmpdef("%r11","T");

    # NOTES:
    # (1) see notes on %r10 in ABI at bottom -- should we use it?
    # (2) a web search on "shared chain" and "x86" only produces 28 results
    # (3) some gcc code uses it as an ordinary register
    # (4) so, use it unless told not to
    regtmpdef("%r10","T")
        unless ($opt_n10);

    # argument registers (a6-a1)
    regtmpdef("%r9","A6");
    regtmpdef("%r8","A5");
    regtmpdef("%rcx","A4");
    regtmpdef("%rdx","A3");
    regtmpdef("%rsi","A2");
    regtmpdef("%rdi","A1");

    # callee preserved registers
    regtmpdef("%r15","P");
    regtmpdef("%r14","P");
    regtmpdef("%r13","P");
    regtmpdef("%r12","P");

    dbgprt(1,"regtmpall: EXIT\n");
}

# regtmpdef -- define usable temp registers
sub regtmpdef
{
    my($sym,$typ) = @_;

    dbgprt(1,"regtmpdef: SYM sym='%s' typ='%s'\n",$sym,$typ);

    push(@regtmplist,$sym);
    $regtmp_type{$sym} = $typ;
}

# regtmploc -- locate temp register to fix problem
sub regtmploc
{
    my($fnx,$fixlist) = @_;
    my($sixlist);
    my($uselook);
    my($regrhs);
    my($fixcnt);
    my($coretyp);
    my($reglhs,$regtyp);

    dbgprt(2,"regtmploc: ENTER fnx_fnc='%s'\n",$fnx->{fnx_fnc});

    $sixlist = $fnx->{fnx_sixlist};
    $fixcnt = @$fixlist;
    $fixcnt = 1
        if ($opt_P);

    $uselook = $fnx->{fnx_used};

    foreach $regrhs (@regtmplist) {
        dbgprt(2,"regtmploc: TRYREG regrhs='%s' uselook=%d\n",
            $regrhs,$uselook->{$regrhs});

        unless ($uselook->{$regrhs}) {
            $regtyp = $regtmp_type{$regrhs};
            $coretyp = $regtyp;
            $coretyp =~ s/\d+$//;

            # function uses stack arguments -- we can't push/pop
            if (($coretyp eq "P") && (@$sixlist > 0)) {
                dbgprt(2,"regtmploc: SIXREJ\n");
                next;
            }

            if (defined($opt_N)) {
                dbgprt(2,"regtmploc: TRYREJ opt_N='%s' regtyp='%s'\n",
                    $opt_N,$regtyp);
                next if ($opt_N =~ /$coretyp/);
            }

            $reglhs = $regrhs;
            last;
        }
    }

    {
        last if (defined($reglhs));

        errprt("regtmploc: unable to locate usable fixup register for function '%s'\n",
            $fnx->{fnx_fnc});

        last if ($fixcnt <= 0);

        $fatal = 1;
    }

    dbgprt(2,"regtmploc: EXIT reglhs='%s' regtyp='%s'\n",$reglhs,$regtyp);

    ($reglhs,$regtyp);
}

# regusejoin -- get regex for all registers
sub regusejoin
{
    my($reg);

    dbgprt(1,"regusejoin: ENTER\n");

    # rax
    foreach $reg (qw(a b c d))  {
        regusedef($reg,"r_x","e_x","_l","_h");
    }

    #   rdi/rsi
    foreach $reg (qw(d s)) {
        regusedef($reg,"r_i","e_i","_i","_il");
    }

    # rsp/rbp
    foreach $reg (qw(b s)) {
        regusedef($reg,"r_p","e_p");
    }

    foreach $reg (8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) {
        regusedef($reg,"r_","r_d","r_w","r_b");
    }

    $regusergx = join("|",reverse(sort(@reguse)));

    dbgprt(1,"regusejoin: EXIT regusergx='%s'\n",$regusergx);
}

# regusedef -- define all registers
sub regusedef
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($mid);
    my($pat);
    my($base);

    $mid = shift(@argv);

    dbgprt(1,"regusedef: ENTER mid='%s'\n",$mid);

    foreach $pat (@argv) {
        $pat = "%" . $pat;
        $pat =~ s/_/$mid/;
        $base //= $pat;
        dbgprt(1,"regusedef: PAT pat='%s' base='%s'\n",$pat,$base);

        push(@reguse,$pat);
        $reguse_tobase{$pat} = $base;
    }

    $reguse_isbase{$base} = 1;

    dbgprt(1,"regusedef: EXIT\n");
}

# regusesort -- sort base register names
sub regusesort
{
    my($symlhs,$numlhs);
    my($symrhs,$numrhs);
    my($cmpflg);

    {
        ($symlhs,$numlhs) = _regusesort($a);
        ($symrhs,$numrhs) = _regusesort($b);

        $cmpflg = $symlhs cmp $symrhs;
        last if ($cmpflg);

        $cmpflg = $numlhs <=> $numrhs;
    }

    $cmpflg;
}

# _regusesort -- split up base register name
sub _regusesort
{
    my($sym) = @_;
    my($num);

    if ($sym =~ s/(\d+)$//) {
        $num = $1;
        $num += 0;
        $sym =~ s/[^%]/z/g;
    }

    ($sym,$num);
}

# optget -- get options
sub optget
{
    my($argv) = @_;
    my($bf);
    my($sym,$val);
    my($dft,%dft);

    foreach $sym (qw(a l n10 P q o s T)) {
        $dft{$sym} = 1;
    }
    $dft{"N"} = "T";
    $dft{"D"} = "DIFF";

    while (1) {
        $bf = $argv->[0];
        $sym = $bf;

        last unless ($sym =~ s/^-//);
        last if ($sym eq "-");

        shift(@$argv);

        {
            if ($sym =~ /([^=]+)=(.+)$/) {
                ($sym,$val) = ($1,$2);
                last;
            }

            if ($sym =~ /^(.)(.+)$/) {
                ($sym,$val) = ($1,$2);
                last;
            }

            undef($val);
        }

        $dft = $dft{$sym};
        sysfault("$pgmtail: unknown option -- '%s'\n",$bf)
            unless (defined($dft));

        $val //= $dft;

        ${"opt_" . $sym} = $val;
    }
}

# cmtprt -- transformation comments
sub cmtprt
{

    $_ = shift(@_);
    $_ = sprintf($_,@_);
    chomp($_);
    push(@cmtprt,$_);
}

# msgprt -- progress output
sub msgprt
{

    printf(STDERR @_);
}

# errprt -- show errors
sub errprt
{

    cmtprt(@_);
    printf(STDERR @_);
}

# sysfault -- abort on error
sub sysfault
{

    printf(STDERR @_);
    exit(1);
}

# dbgprt -- debug print
sub dbgprt
{

    $_ = shift(@_);
    goto &_dbgprt
        if ($opt_T >= $_);
}

# _dbgprt -- debug print
sub _dbgprt
{

    printf(STDERR @_);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the script to fix bugs, add more checking, and more options. *Note:* I had to remove ABI at bottom to fit 30,000 limit.

> Otherwise weird results appear on other commands with parentheses for example `cmpl %ebp, (%rax,%r14)` splits into `lhs='cmpl %ebp, (%rax'` and `rhs='%r14)'` which in turn causes `/$rhs/` to fail.

Yes, that was a bug. Fixed.

> Your `$rhs =~ /%[er](.x|\d+)/` doesn't match byte or word loads to `di`, or `ax`. That's unlikely, though. Oh, also, I think it fails to match `rdi / rsi`.  so you don't need the trailing d in r10d

Fixed. Finds all variants.

> Wow, I assumed something like this would have to happen at compile time, and that doing it after the fact would be too messy.

*Shameless plug:* Thanks for the "Wow!". `perl` is great for messy jobs like this. I've written assembler "injection" scripts like this before. (e.g.) Back in the day [before compiler support] to add profiling calls.

> You could mark %r10 as another call-preserved register.

After doing a few web searches, I could only find about 84 matches on `"static chain" x86`. The only one of relevance was the x86 ABI. And, it offered no explanation other than to mention it as a footnote. Also, some `gcc` code uses `r10` *without* any save as a *callee* register. So, I've now defaulted the program to use `r10` (with a command line option to disable it if desired).

> What happens if a function already uses all the registers?

If it's *truly* all, then we're out of luck. The script will detect and report this and suppress fixups if it can't find a spare register.

And, it *will* use a "callee must preserve" register by injecting a `push` as the 1st inst of the function and a corresponding `pop` just before the `ret` inst [can have multiple]. This can be disabled with an option.

> You can't just push/pop, because that steps on the red-zone

No, it does *not*. For a few reasons:

(1) Almost as a side note: The red zone is only useful in leaf functions. Otherwise, if `fncA` calls `fncB`, the mere act of doing this by `fncA` would step on it's own red zone. See compile options in the script's top comment block.

(2) More importantly, because of the way that the `push/pop` is injected. The `push` occurs *before* any other insts. The `pop` occurs *after* any other insts [just before the `ret`].

The red zone is still there--intact. It is just offset by -8 from where it would have been otherwise. All red zone activity is preserved because these insts use *negative* offsets from `%rsp`

This is *different* than a `push/pop` done inside an inline asm block. The usual case is red zone code doing (e.g.) `mov $23,-4(%rsp)`. An inline asm block coming afterwards that does a `push/pop` *would* step on that.

Some functions to show this:

```
# function_original -- original function before pebsfixup
# RETURNS: 23
function_original:
    mov     $23,-4(%rsp)                # red zone code generated by compiler
    ...
    mov     -4(%rsp),%rax               # will still have $23
    ret

# function_pebsfixup -- pebsfixup modified
# RETURNS: 23
function_pebsfixup:
    push    %r12                        # pebsfixup injected

    mov     $23,-4(%rsp)                # red zone code generated by compiler
    ...
    mov     -4(%rsp),%rax               # will still have $23

    pop     %r12                        # pebsfixup injected
    ret

# function_inline -- function with inline asm block and red zone
# RETURNS: unknown value
function_inline:
    mov     $23,-4(%rsp)                # red zone code generated by compiler

    # inline asm block -- steps on red zone
    push    %rdx
    push    %rcx
    ...
    pop     %rcx
    pop     %rdx

    ...

    mov     -4(%rsp),%rax               # now -4(%rsp) no longer has $23

    ret
```

Where the `push/pop` *does* get us in trouble is if the function uses *more* than six arguments (i.e. args 7+ are on the stack). Access to these arguments use a *positive* offset from `%rsp`:

```
mov     32(%rsp),%rax
```

With our "trick" `push`, the offset will be incorrect. The correct offset would now be 8 higher:

```
mov     40(%rsp),%rax
```

The script will *detect* this and complain. But, it does not [yet] adjust the positive offsets as this case is low probability. It would probably take about five more lines of code to fix this. Punting for now ...

Comment: Also, nice digging on `r10`.  My impression was that C compiler output would treat it as a scratch reg, but I took the safe suggestion of treating it as call-preserved.  (Although I'm not even sure *how* it gets used for languages that do use it.  Its value during child calls might actually matter, not just on return to the parent.)  This would be a gotcha if you were instrumenting code from a language that used it, but not for C/C++.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, finally found something on static chain. See the info pages for `gcc`. Just found it, but haven't yet read enough of it. Also, `gcc-manual.pdf` "Using and Porting the GNU Compiler Collection" [Stallman] for gcc-3.0 [last updated 14 June 2001].

Comment: @Cimbali I've updated the script to use `lea` [plus a bugfix against clang `.s`, some features, and more comments]. Glad you got something working. The register "already in use" scan is better/fixed from orig, so be mindful of that. Even if you want to work from orig, have a look. I'd be interested to know how things work out when the script is "in full production", so send me a comment

Comment: @CraigEstey I've imported all your updates, this is really a great answer. I've had to convert it to some language I'm reasonably familiar with, but as long as it has regular expressions... have a look, I've put it online here: https://gist.github.com/Cimbali/2aea56e01959cb4bf801 (I think the only difference functionally is that I allow dots in labels, which I discovered I had)

Comment: @Cimbali I learned some `python` recently so I'll review in depth. Good call on refactoring into more functions. I didn't like the [massive] `dofile` and was going to split it. The dots in labels [AFAICT--I found a few in my code] are for `openmp` [hidden] thread functions that are auto generated [fixed]. I also have a few functions that had more than 6 args and needed fixup using a saved reg, so I've added the "positive offset" fixup code. I'm going to build a test script that will run your script and mine on all my source files and report diffs [if any]. Will let you know ...