# C Preprocessor to insert code after every statement

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm assuming this is impossible, but I've seen plenty of crazy preprocessor magic before so I thought I'd ask. Can the preprocessor insert code after every statement between two points?

For example, I have the following code:

```
// ...
dy2 = dy2 + (rand()%3) - 1;                                swapTask();
if (dy2 < D2Upper) dy2 = D2Upper;                          swapTask();
if (dy2 > D2Lower) dy2 = D2Lower;                          swapTask();
dy2 = (dy2+9) >= dy1 ? dy1-9 : dy2;                        swapTask();

if (direction2 > 0)
{
    memcpy(&pk[dy2+0][direction2+7], "_", 1);              swapTask();
    memcpy(&pk[dy2+1][direction2+6], "/o\\", 3);           swapTask();
    memcpy(&pk[dy2+2][direction2+4], "</ _<", 5);          swapTask();
    memcpy(&pk[dy2+3][direction2+3], "</ /", 4);           swapTask();
    memcpy(&pk[dy2+4][direction2+2], "</ ==x", 6);         swapTask();
    memcpy(&pk[dy2+5][direction2+3], "/  \\", 4);          swapTask();
    memcpy(&pk[dy2+6][direction2+2], "//)__)", 6);         swapTask();
    memcpy(&pk[dy2+7][direction2+0], "<<< \\_ \\_", 9);    swapTask();
    if (++direction2 > D2Right)
        direction2 = -direction2;                          swapTask();
}
// ...
```

I need to call `swapTask();` after each statement. This becomes bothersome over time (especially if I want it to look nice and aligned).

Originally I thought of programmatically adding it to each line, but that obviously breaks block-less `if` statements. Then I thought of adding it after each semicolon, but that obviously breaks `for` statements. Is there any preprocessor, compiler, or other method of magic that can call this after each line? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible -- but I'll just mention that you can avoid breaking blockless `if` statements by not using blockless `if` statements.

Comment: This smells incredibly of XY problem... For example most of that code could probably be rewritten using a loop, so you'd have the `swapTask()` called inside the loop and be done.

Comment: This is not possible with the preprocessor.

Comment: Can you give us an idea what your program is doing when it calls `swapTask`?

Comment: Using the preprocessor would be cleaner, but I think a well-chosen regex with `sed` on your file could temporarily do the trick.

Comment: @jacob swapTask uses a setjmp/longjmp to do a context switch to an entirely different part of the code. AFAIK, It's a pseudo-threading model that's being used for teaching OS task swapping/running/blocking/etc. We are instructed to put it on every line, but I hoping there was an automated way

Comment: This can be done with a script. As an example, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630949/keep-target-address-of-load-in-register-until-instruction-is-retired/35694557#35694557 This does it by injecting into the assembler output, but the general approach can [more] easily be applied to the C source. But, what are you really trying to do? For example, do you want the changes permanent or have the script run each time during the build? More information could help

Comment: @JonathanGawrych In practice, you would only call `swapTask()` every once in a while (e.g. on every function entry or so). Calling it after every line of code is not very useful in real programs as each call takes time.

Comment: You could try `#define ; ;swapTask();`, but my hopes are not high that it'd work... :-)

Comment: @FUZxxl True, in practice this is silly and counter-productive overkill. I wouldn't ever use this in real life, but have to for an assignment

Comment: Whoever told you so seems to have no idea about programming, less C. That is one of the most awful ideas I ever headers. Co-op multitasking does not work at that level and that approach can well break the program logic.

Comment: There's techniques to write an iterating macro. You could try that and pass your entire code into it. But it would probably look a bit iffy. And it probably wouldn't solve the issue with braceless ifs.

Comment: @SteveSummit the macro identifier must begin with an alphabet character.

Comment: Echoing what @Olaf said: trying to implement "cooperative multitasking" using exhaustive, explicit, per-line `swapTask()` calls is a terrible, horrible, no good, very bad idea.  Do just enough of it to keep your misguided instructor happy, but then, please, forget all about it!

Comment: Maybe `#define S(x) do { x; } while (swapTask(), 0)`

Comment: You can't use `setjmp()/longjump()` to emulate context-switch. You'd need something like `getcontext()/setcontext()`.

Comment: Call `amemcpy` instead of `memcpy` and define `amemcpy` as your two calls.